# project works fine on Xcode 9.0.1 but shows errors on Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Please help me I have no idea why it shows error in my Mac with Xcode 9.2 but the same project works fine with a Mac which has Xcode 9.0.1.

The errors it throws are

- Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.3
- Header '****-Swift.h' not found
- Could not build Objective-C module '****Lib'
- Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
- clang: error: no such file or directory

are the errors due to some missing files? please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 4.0 is compatible with Swift 3.2 only.

Swift 4.0.1 is compatible with Swift 3.2.1 only.

So:

you can't mix 4.0 and 3.2.3

you can't mix 4.0.1 and 3.2

you can't mix 4.0 and 4.0.1

you can't mix 3.2.3 and 3.2

It's possible to build using Swift 3.2.3 in Xcode 9.2 by installing the Xcode 9.0 toolchain and using that to build your project.

Swift Toolchain Image

Then choose the Swift 4.0 release under the Xcode -> Toolchains menu.

You should now be able to build with either Swift 3.2 or 4.0 in Xcode 9.2.